# Trouble running a batch file with a space in the path and space in the argument

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arguments

I am trying to run a batch file that's located in:

```
C:\Test Batch\BatchTest.bat
```

That will copy a file from another specified location, let's say

```
C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Company Downloads\downloadedDoc.doc
```

I can run the batch file as:

```
cmd  /c start "" "C:\Test Batch\TestBatch.bat"
```

And the batch actually does run.

But when I try to add an argument for it to copy like this:

```
cmd  /c start "" "C:\Test Batch\TestBatch.bat" "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop\Company Downloads\downloadedDoc.doc"
```

I get:

```
'C:\Test' is not recognized a an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Ultimately the batch file and file to be copied will be specified by a user and will likely have spaces in the names or path. So a simple answer to use paths without spaces will not suffice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try changing the startup directory with the /d argument to start like so:

```
cmd /c start "" /d"C:\Test Batch\" "TestBatch.bat" "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop\Company Downloads\downloadedDoc.doc"
```

The start command has some oddities parsing quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have to get this working today. I tried using the double quotes just as you mentioned above. But now I get a windows popup that says "Windows cannot find 'C:\Test'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again." I also wonder if this will affect my ability to run this in java using Runtime.exec(String []) where I may get the embedded quotes error.

Comment: The good thing is that the Runtime.exec(String []) method doesn't mind the extra quotes. But I still get the same error as above. I know its not a typo because I am browsing to those files to get the paths and names in my application. I'm running windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Yeah I just gave it a shot and passing a quoted executable path and a quoted argument to start would not work for me with any quote configuration until I used the /d argument to change start's working directory. Updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me from the command prompt. Now I just have to parse out the path and the batch file into separate strings (which is easy enough) and I think I'm good.

Answer (score 13):

It's a known *feature* of `cmd.exe` which is started by `start.exe`. This happens only when the command has a space in its name or path and at least one of the arguments is quoted.

A workaround is to replace the command with a `call`.

```
start "" CALL "C:\Test Batch\TestBatch.bat" "C:\Users\User Name\down.doc"
```

Comment: This should really be the correct answer...the accepted one is too long and requires knowing the working directory beforehand, which for me, is impossible.

Comment: To me it looks like it's not a space in the command path/name, rather has it to be quoted to cause that strange issue…